# Lexer and parser generators for C/C++ able to process input part by part

Tags: c++, parsing, lexer

I am looking for a lexer and parser generators able to create automatons which work in "push" mode for input, that is they do not read input on they own but expect me to feed them more. Preferable interface would be similar to:

```
Lexer l;
Parser p;

while (read_more_input(buffer) != EOF) {
    l.feed(buffer);
    while (p.has_token() != false) { // so more input needed
        p.feed(l.get_token());
        if (p.has_partial_result() == true) {
            do_something(p.get_result());        
        }
    }
}
```

I need such generators for simple reason - I'm doing asynchronous network server (with boost::asio), which means that I consume input in parts, and I have to parse it part by part.

I did my homework and found a pair of tools that seems to do the job, namely [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) and [re2c](http://re2c.org/), but I'd love to hear about other tools.

Comment: [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) for lexical analysis & [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/) for parsing

Comment: show me how to use flex in a way that i describe without going through hassle of creating in-memory stream, separate threads and other such constructions.

Comment: Yes, (f)lex does not provide a push mode. Bison does, and as you say, so does Lemon.